# hideTab in a shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that uses the `navbarPage` layout. Every tab in the app is a shiny module and each tab has various sub tabs. Based on a user login, certain tabs/sub tabs need to be hidden. As these are modules, I am not sure how to go about achieving this. Here’s a toy example which does not work. My aim here is to hide the tab panel called ‘Second DB Panel’

```
library(shiny)

#Module for first tab
mod_home_tab_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    title = 'Home',
    value = 'home',
    tabsetPanel(
      id = ns('first_set'),
      tabPanel('First Home Panel'),
      tabPanel('Second Home Panel')
    )
  )
}

mod_home_tab_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
  })
}

#Module for second tab
mod_second_tab_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    title = 'Dashboards',
    value = 'db',
    tabsetPanel(
      id = ns('second_set'),
      tabPanel('First DB Panel'),
      tabPanel('Second DB Panel')
    )
  )
}

mod_second_tab_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
  })
}

#Shiny App
ui <- navbarPage(
  "example",
  id = "all_tabs",
  mod_home_tab_ui('home_tab'),
  mod_second_tab_ui('second_tab')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # Logic to read in the username and then hide tabs:
  hideTab('second_set', 'Second DB Panel', session = getDefaultReactiveDomain())
  
  mod_home_tab_server('home_tab')
  mod_second_tab_server('second_tab')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This has perhaps got something to do with passing the correct session information to the `hideTab` function, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Typos.  `home-tab` and `second_tab` in the app UI and `home_tab`and `second_set` in the call to `hideTab` in the app server.

Comment: @Limey thanks corrected it. For `hideTab`, I am referring to the `id` of the `tabsetPanel` which contains the `tabPanel` that I want to hide. Hence `second_set` and this is what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It works if the `id` of the `tabsetPanel` is provided without the namespace:

```
tabsetPanel(
      id = 'second_set',
      tabPanel('First DB Panel'),
      tabPanel('Second DB Panel')
    )
```